# Pandas read_sql

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I encountered the following irregularities and wanted to share my solution.

I'm reading a sql table from Microsoft SQL Server in Python using Pandas and SQLALCHEMY. There is a column called "occurtime" with the following format: "2017-01-01 01:01:11.000". Using SQLAlchemy to read the "occurtime" column, everything was returned as NaN. I tried to set the parse_date parameter in the `pandas.read_sql()` method but with no success.

Is anyone else encountering issue reading a datetime column from a SQL table using SQLAlchemy/Pandas?

Comment: What is the data type of this column on the SQL Server side?

Answer (score 0):

I had to work around the datetime column from my SQL query itself just so SQLAlchemy/Pandas can stop reading it as a NaN value.

In my SQL query, I used `CONVERT()` to convert the datetime column to a string. This was ready with no issue, and then I used `pandas.to_datetime()` to convert it back into datetime.

Anyone else with a better solution or know what's really going on, please share your answer, I'd really appreciate it!!!