# how to close pandas read_sql connection

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

The following code yields an error that says the database is locked:

```
    df_chunks = pd.read_sql('cdr', engine, chunksize=100000)
    engine.dispose()
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        trans = conn.begin()
        query = """
        CREATE TABLE test (row_id BIGINT,ego_id BIGINT,alter_id BIGINT)
        """
        print(query)
        conn.execute(query)
        trans.commit()
        conn.close()
```

but if I do it the other way around:

```
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        trans = conn.begin()
        query = """
        CREATE TABLE test (row_id BIGINT,ego_id BIGINT,alter_id BIGINT)
        """
        print(query)
        conn.execute(query)
        trans.commit()
        conn.close()
    df_chunks = pd.read_sql('cdr', engine, chunksize=100000)
```

it works and I am able to generate the new table. So from here, it seems that the problem is that `pd.read_sql` (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)) locks the database. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197851/pandas-read-sql) but `engine.dispose()` didn't work for me. What's the way to go around this problem?

Comment: What is `'cdr'`? Please point to documentation of this method.

Comment: @Parfait 'cdr' is simply the table name. I'm adding the link to the documentation in the original post above.

Answer (score 3):

Because `chunksize` builds a generator of data frames and you never do anything with `df_chunks`, this object may still hold a pointer to source object, `engine`, and therefore "locks" the database. To resolve your first attempt, consider running an iteration on the `df_chunks`:

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
    trans = conn.begin()
    query = """CREATE TABLE test (row_id BIGINT,ego_id BIGINT,alter_id BIGINT)
            """
    print(query)
    conn.execute(query)
    trans.commit()

df_chunks = pd.read_sql('cdr', engine, chunksize=100000)

for df in df_chunks:
    # DO SOMETHING WITH EACH df

engine.dispose()                     # ALLOWED SINCE GENERATOR IS EXHAUSTED AFTER for LOOP
```

Alternatively, to resolve your second attempt, integrate your `read_sql` call inside `with` block and use the `conn` object.

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
    trans = conn.begin()
    query = """CREATE TABLE test (row_id BIGINT,ego_id BIGINT,alter_id BIGINT)
            """
    print(query)
    conn.execute(query)
    trans.commit()

    # INDENT LINE AND USE conn OBJECT
    df_chunks = pd.read_sql('cdr', conn, chunksize=100000)

    for df in df_chunks:
        # DO SOMETHING WITH EACH df

engine.dispose()                     # CLOSE engine OBJECT NOT conn
```

Also, when using `with` as a context manager, it is unnecessary to call close: `conn.close()`.

Comment: Actually, the original code (before I tried to debug where the error came from, hence this simpler "create table" alteration) actually had something like "for df in df_chunks: <do something>", but that <do something> includes making another dataframe (based on the dataframe from the generator) and then writing it into the same database, basically a `new_df.to_sql('new_table', engine)`. It gave the same error.